# Using DCMI Interface but only receiving 0xA603A603 before hard fault

Tags: c, stm32

For my master thesis I am trying to receive data over DCMI with the STM32H742. As an image sensor I am using the NOIV2SN1300A. It sends data over 10 data lines, this data differs (so not always `0xA603A603`). To reduce data size I have activated binning and subsampling.

I am using DMA to transfer the data received by DCMI into the internal SRAM at address `0x24000000`. After a few telegrams (of `0xA603A603`) the uC goes into hard fault and infinite loop. I am not sure why this error occurs. Here is my config for DMA and DCMI:

```
   /* DCMI DMA Init */

   /* DCMI Init */

   hdma_dcmi.Instance = DMA1_Stream0;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_DCMI;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;//WORD;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.Mode = DMA_DOUBLE_BUFFER_M0;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;

   hdma_dcmi.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;

   //hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;

   if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_dcmi) != HAL_OK)

   {

     Error_Handler();

   }

 

   __HAL_LINKDMA(hdcmi,DMA_Handle,hdma_dcmi);

 

   HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DCMI_IRQn, 0, 0);

   HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DCMI_IRQn);

 

   HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);

   HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn);
```

```
 hdcmi.Instance = DCMI;

 hdcmi.Init.SynchroMode = DCMI_SYNCHRO_HARDWARE;

 hdcmi.Init.PCKPolarity = DCMI_PCKPOLARITY_FALLING;   //Todo:???

 hdcmi.Init.VSPolarity = DCMI_VSPOLARITY_HIGH;

 hdcmi.Init.HSPolarity = DCMI_HSPOLARITY_HIGH;

 hdcmi.Init.CaptureRate = DCMI_CR_ALL_FRAME;

 hdcmi.Init.ExtendedDataMode = DCMI_EXTEND_DATA_10B;

 hdcmi.Init.JPEGMode = DCMI_JPEG_DISABLE;

 hdcmi.Init.ByteSelectMode = DCMI_BSM_OTHER;//DCMI_BSM_ALL;

 hdcmi.Init.ByteSelectStart = DCMI_OEBS_ODD;

 hdcmi.Init.LineSelectMode = DCMI_LSM_ALL;

 hdcmi.Init.LineSelectStart = DCMI_OELS_ODD;

 if (HAL_DCMI_Init(&hdcmi) != HAL_OK)

 {

   Error_Handler();

 }
```

```
uint32_t DataSizeImageSensor = 0xB160;
```

```
DMA_BUFFER uint32_t AddressFrameBuffer[0xB160];
```

```
HAL_DCMI_Start_DMA(&hdcmi, DCMI_MODE_SNAPSHOT, (uint32_t)AddressFrameBuffer, DataSizeImageSensor);
```

```
void MPU_Config (void)
{
  MPU_Region_InitTypeDef MPU_InitStruct;

  /* Disable the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Disable();

  /* Configure the MPU attributes for SDRAM */
  MPU_InitStruct.Enable = MPU_REGION_ENABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.BaseAddress = 0x24000000;
  MPU_InitStruct.Size = MPU_REGION_SIZE_512KB;
  MPU_InitStruct.AccessPermission = MPU_REGION_FULL_ACCESS;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsBufferable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_BUFFERABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.IsCacheable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_CACHEABLE;        //Cache is incoherent with CPU for DMA usage
  MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_SHAREABLE;
  MPU_InitStruct.Number = MPU_REGION_NUMBER0;
  MPU_InitStruct.TypeExtField = MPU_TEX_LEVEL1;
  MPU_InitStruct.SubRegionDisable = 0x00;
  MPU_InitStruct.DisableExec = MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_DISABLE;

  HAL_MPU_ConfigRegion(&MPU_InitStruct);

  /* Enable the MPU */
  HAL_MPU_Enable(MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT);
}
```

Any idea why this error occurs? Like I said, I receive data, I am sure the sensor sends viable data (so something else then `0xA603A603`), but I get only the same data by DCMI before hard fault. At this current setup I transfer 64 telegrams, then the hard fault occurs. Furthermore I disabled the cache for the SRAM1, as there are problems regarding cache/DMA/CPU coherence. I am not quite sure how to proceed, as it looks to me like it is a setup error. Maybe an overrun by DCMI?

Note: The code above doesn't actually occur in this order. That are just the relevant parts (at least from what I expect to be relevant).

I found other posts about this problem, where the error was a slow system clock. As my system clock is 475 MHz and the HCLK3 Clock (which is used by DCMI for sampling) is 237.5 MHz I can rule out a Clock problem. The datasheet says the HCLK Clock has to be 2.5 times faster then DCMI Clock (which is set by the image sensor with 62 Mhz).

Comment: first of all identify the source of the HF. If you do not know how install atollic studio which has a built in HF plugin. It will give you all the information needed

Comment: The interrupt source seems to be interrupt 3, which is RTC_WKUP_IRQn.

Comment: I was following the described way under "Debugging a ARM Cortex-M Hard Fault" https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html. But to be honest the RTC_WKUP_IRQn makes no sense at all to me

Comment: it does not matter as all not having separate handlers interrupts are set tot default handler. I asked about what has invoked it. What kind of HF it is. Is it precise or not? etc etc

Comment: The invoke seems to come from the WWDG_IRQHandler. I also try to use the Fault Analyzer (using STM32CubeIDE), but the Fault Analyzer does not seem to detect any fault.

Comment: Currently I am able to receive the full frame. But directly after the last byte is tranfered in my buffer the signal handler is called and the WWDG_IRQHandler is called (even though I dont even use a WWDG). The commentary of the Default Handler suggests that the processer received an unexpected interrupt and enters an infinite loop.

Comment: `Default Handler suggests that the processer received an unexpected interrupt` no it is 100% wrong assumption

Comment: But why do I get an interrupt of the WWDG? I dont even initialize the WWDG. And this problem only occurs in  collaboration with DCMI, without this my code works perfectly fine.

Comment: I have already explained it. The topic too broad to explain it in forum.

Comment: So I checked the Register which containts the information over the Interrupt. Register SCB->CFSR_UFSR_BFSR_MMFSR @ address 0xE000ED28. The value of this register after the hard fault is 0x0. Also the Fault Analyzer does not detect any fault.